# Sql injection and updateall cakephp issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm running into a problem in cakephp when I use this query

```
$this->Rh->CompetencesUser->updateAll(array(
    'CompetencesUser.niveau' => "'$value[1]'",
    'CompetencesUser.expertise' => $value[2],
    'CompetencesUser.rh_id' => $this->Rh->getLastInsertId()
), array(
    'CompetencesUser.user_id' => $this->request->params['pass'][0],
    'CompetencesUser.competence_id' => $value[3]
));
```

it works but when I give some characters like ' in the field `$value[1]` it shows an error, so how I can escape this character or can I use another method, because the `$value[1]` don't work without adding those quotes.

Comment: @Holt According to [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions): The $fields array accepts SQL expressions, so literal values should be quoted manually.

Comment: i thought this to but when i give for example a string like home, i got this sql error saying field home unkonwn column and because there's no quote in it. it should be something like 'home' and it works. i find it very stupid to add quotes that why im asking. Cake should do that

Comment: oki, now i understand, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions:) "Literal values should be quoted manually using DboSource::value()."

For example:-

```
$db = $this->Rh->CompetencesUser->getDataSource();
$this->Rh->CompetencesUser->updateAll(
    ['CompetencesUser.niveau' => $db->value($value[1], 'string')],
    [ // Some conditions ]
);
```

In most cases `updateAll()` is not the right choice of method for saving data and `save()` would be better suited. Take a look at [Use CakePHP 2's updateAll() Method with Caution!](http://andy-carter.com/blog/use-cakephp-2-s-updateall-method-with-caution)

Comment: In my case I had to use updateAll because Cake 2 refuses to acknowledge what a composite primary key is.