# How to write update query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

```
$test="test's";   
$contact='1234567890';
 $this->Page->updateAll(
        array('Page.order' => 0,"Page.name" => "'$test'","Page.contact" => "'$contact'"),
        array('Page.type' => 'PROMOTED')
    );
```

Above query having single quote conflict. Is there any other way to write update query . I am using cakephp 2x

Comment: why are you single quoting PHP variable?

Comment: $this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data); . I used this method but its inserting record not updating .

Comment: incorrect, as soon as you set the id it doesnt insert it updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql injection and and updateall cakephp issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068783/sql-injection-and-and-updateall-cakephp-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**: Must backslash characters that have another meaning in php if you want them to be recognized as string caharacters. e.g(test's needs be test\'s)

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions

try:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$test = $db->value('test\'s');
$contact = $db->value('1234567890');
$this->Page->updateAll(
        array('Page.order' => 0,"Page.name" => $test,"Page.contact" =>     $contact),
    array('Page.type' => 'PROMOTED')
);
```

Comment: Have a closer look at the docs that you've linked, CakePHP will _not_ auto-quote the values in an `updateAll()` call!

Comment: yeah sorry, your dead right.But even in the documentation they don't literal quote a variable. see if my updated answer is any help.